# Why this programme doesn't print the value 2 .. My desire output is 2.. where is the error here

Tags: c, for-loop, equation-solving, nested-for-loop

**sample code is here**, desire output is `2` ::

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double i, a, b;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i = i + .20)
    {

        if (i == 2)
        {
            printf("I=%lf\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

***When I use***

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>     double i, a, b;
>     int j;
>     for (i = 0; i <= 3; i = i + .25)
>     {
>
>         if (i == 2)
>         {
>             printf("I=%lf\n", i);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

it works; but in the first case, it is not working. WHY ??

Comment: It is because double can not represent .20 precisely but can do so with .25, print your variable at the start of the loop and see for yourself.

Comment: If you `printf("%.16f\n", i);` in each loop you'll see the first example gives `1.9999999999999998`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the use of a floating control variable for a `for` loop is unwise... comparing a floating value for equality is even less so.

Due to the storage of floating point numbers as a mantissa and an exponent, your `0.20000000` may well be `0.199999999...9` or `020000000...01` thus the comparison fails.

Typically, `0.25` and `2.000` will store exactly, as they are powers of 2. Hence a step of `0.25` works as anticipated.

MISRA C:2012 has Rule 14.1 to protect against using `float` or `doubles` as loop counters... and previously had a Rule to protect against testing `float`/`double` for equality -perhaps we should reinstate that Rule.

Comment: But sir , I don't understand this clearly . How can I get read of this problem??

Comment: Let's talk offline (as the question is closed) - connect with me on LinkedIn and drop me an email address